# "No peer certificate" android application

Tags: android, ssl, httpconnection

i'm working on an application for android devices( 2.2).
I'm trying to get an html page.The java code I use seems to work, so I can obtain the page I want, but sometimes the app crashes and i get the exception: "no peer certificate". When this happens, if I wait one hour or I change network, it works normally. Does someone know how to solve this? 
The site is https://stud.infostud.uniroma1.it/Sest/Log/

I'm really sorry about my english, I hope you'll understand!

Comment: This works on Froyo and Gingerbread: http://www.virtualzone.de/2011-02-27/how-to-use-apache-httpclient-with-httpsssl-on-android

Answer (score 7):

When I was getting that exception it was because my phones date was not correctly set. I just switched back to using the network provided date and everything worked.

Comment: Confirming that: when the date of my tablet was reset to some day in January 2002, I could not connect to the internet using the Play Store or the Gmail client (but the browser could connect to the internet). The log would say: 01-02 11:12:41.760: E/Gmail(995): IOException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCert PathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Fri Jan 02 11:12:41 HNEC 1970, validation time: Mon Jun 08 22:43:27 HNEC 2009.
Changing the date/time to the correct one, fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this before you make the network call:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

It sounds like you're having issues with a known issue that causes Android to break when trying to be clever with its connections. If that doesn't work check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352424/httpurlconnection-openconnection-fails-second-time)

Comment: Do you have a 2.3 device handy (could try the emulator). If that works, there's an issue with the certificate - Android 2.2 or earlier doesn't trust many CAs

Comment: I've already tried with other version(2.3 too)...same problem. When I got the problem, I tried to connect with the phone browser and I got the same exception. With my laptop everything works.

Comment: I have noticed only now that: 
the server use 256-bit cryptography with AES_256_CBC SHA1 for authentication message, and RSA for keys exchange..
also, server use TLS 1.0!

can be this the issue?
how can i solve it?
Thanks a lot! ;)