# Second HttpUrlConnection hangs on real device

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm using [basic-http-client](https://code.google.com/p/basic-http-client/) in my longpolling library [SignalA](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA). basic-http-client is based on HttpUrlConnection. When running in the emulator is it possible to have one longrunning post-request open and do another simultaneous post-request. 
When running my code on a real device the second POST is hanging until the first has completed. It's hanging on the getResponseCode function.

Whats the difference between running in the emulator or on a real device? 
How can I enable multiple AND simultaneous request?

Comment: Use a executor. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Answer (score 1):

Quoting solution from similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352424/httpurlconnection-openconnection-fails-second-time) :-

The connection pool used by `HttpURLConnection` when it is keeping connections alive is broken such that it tries to use connections that have been closed by the server. By default Android sets KeepAlive on all connections.

`System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");` is a workaround that disables KeepAlive for all connections so then you avoid the bug in the connection pool.

`conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");` turns KeepAlive on for this particular connection, essentially reversing what `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");` does.

Also I always explicitly call connect() as it makes it clear where you are ending your connection setup. I'm not sure if calling this method is optional or not.

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mURL.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false); 
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", useragent);
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setDoOutput(true); 
conn.setDoInput(true); 
consumer.sign(conn);

conn.connect();

InputSource is = new InputSource(conn.getInputStream());
```