# HttpURLConnection and JSONParser simultaneous connection

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I have one activity (MainActivity) that uses HttpURLConnection to upload a file using AsyncTask. That all works fine and dandy. I also have another activity (ListAllFilesActivity) that uses a JSONParser with makeHttpRequest to query a MySQL database for a list of all the files that have been uploaded (also using AsyncTask). ListAllFilesActivity activity works great as well.

The problem I'm running into is that if I start a file upload for a large file from MainActivity and then launch ListAllFilesActivity to query the database, the database query will not return a result until the AsyncTask for MainActivity has completed uploading the file (it just shows the progress dialog until the upload is finished). I'm guessing this has something to do with it waiting for the connection to be "released". Is there a way to be able to connect and get results from ListAllFilesActivity while a file is being uploaded in MainActivity?

Not sure exactly what code to show, but here are some snippets. If you need more, please let me know.

MainActivity.java

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);

// open a URL connection to the Servlet
// Open a HTTP connection to the URL
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Allow Inputs
conn.setDoInput(true);
// Allow Outputs
conn.setDoOutput(true);
// Don't use a cached copy.
conn.setUseCaches(false);
// Use a post method.
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
    // Needed to add this since the second attempt to upload a file would fail with an EOFException and IOException: null
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352424/httpurlconnection-openconnection-fails-second-time
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
}
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
// String to get length to use for setFixedLengthStreamingMode
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(infoSize);
```

ListAllFilesActivity.java

List params = new ArrayList();
    // getting JSON string from URL

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", mAccessToken));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gplus_id", mGPlusId));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", mId));

JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

try {
    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

    if (success == 1) {
        // Files found...dump them to HashMap
        // Getting Array of Products
    } 
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with `DONUT`, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Comment: Thanks kabuko, that's good to know. It didn't occur to me that it would be a limitation with AsyncTask. I guess a follow-up question would be: should I use a Thread/Handler instead for the file upload (since there's really no UI dependency, so to speak, when it's finished uploading) and the AsyncTask for getting the list (since it populates the UI when done)? From a user experience point of view it would be nice to not have to wait for the file upload to finish before viewing the list from the other activity. I'm [researching](http://bit.ly/14JemmZ), but a second opinion is nice.

Comment: You should probably consider if the lifetime of these uploads should be tied to the UI. Given that you suggest there's no dependency and that this is a fairly long-running task, it might make sense to do this in a `Service` instead, probably with an `IntentService`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'll look into IntentService.