# Google http/oauth2 api always throws EOFException for second HTTPRequest

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, httprequest, google-oauth

I'm new to android. I tried to implement a simple client/server connection using OAuth2, the process is,

1. try to connect to OAuth2 server with ClientCredentials (client_id and client_secret) and get an access token.
2. using the access token to register a user.

So it involves two rounds of connection. The first round is always fine, the second round of http connection always returns EOFException, which makes me quite confused. The related code is as follows (it is contained in a procedure which runs in a new thread).

```
NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory factory = new JacksonFactory();
//use http for testing only, will use https for deployed environment
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://192.168.x.x/oauth2/token");
//client_id & client_secret
BasicAuthentication auth = new BasicAuthentication("abc","abc");
ClientCredentialsTokenRequest token =
     new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest(transport, factory, url)
           .setClientAuthentication(auth);
TokenResponse response = token.execute();

//ok, i can get access token in response without problem

Credential credential = 
      new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod())
             .setFromTokenResponse(response);
//note that I reuse the transport, but using a new transport2 doesn't help
HttpRequestFactory rf = trasport.createRequestFactory(credential);
GenericData data = new GenericData();
data.put("Username",phoneText.getText().toString());
data.put("Password", passwordText.getText().toString());
JsonHttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(factory, data);
GenericUrl genericUrl=new GenericUrl("http://192.168.x.x/users");
HttpRequest request = rf.buildPostRequest(genericUrl, content);

//the following will always return EOF exception
HttpResponse response=request.execute();
```

May I know why it happens and how to solve it?

Am I using the google http/oauth2 api correctly?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards,

Comment: Can you try and first play the conversation out manually, in the browser? This to check that the token is valid for the url, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re on Android, if at all possible you should use the [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) class from Google Play Services, rather than trying to do the OAuth dance from inside your Android app.  Any accounts that are on the phone are pre-authenticated and it’s very easy to get access tokens for anything reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the [connection pool getting polluted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704083/1081101). Try disabling the keep alive before you do any request:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

Or you can also try to add the following header to your requests:

```
request.addHeader("connection", "close")
```