# Android Volley double post when have slow request

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a problem with Volley POST request on slow network. Everytime I see `BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests` in my LogCat, my POST request is executed twice or more resulting multiple (2 or more) postings for 1 request. I already set the retry policy to 0, but It doesn't help.

This is my LogCat

> 03-16 01:31:35.674: D/Volley(5984): [19807]
>   BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ]
>   http://[myserver]/api/places 0xfa7d0c33 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3824],
>   [size=313], [rc=200], [retryCount=0] 03-16 01:31:35.704:
>   D/Volley(5984): [1] Request.finish: 3853 ms: [ ]
>   http://[myserver]/api/places 0xfa7d0c33 NORMAL 1

This is my code

```
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
try {
    body.put(PROTO_BODY_AUTHORIZATION, Sessions.getActiveSession().getToken());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,
        context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_address) + "/places",
        body,
        callback,
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
);

request.setRetryPolicy(
        new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

Please help, I desperately finding solution for this problem.

Comment: Is your network request timeout the same amount of seconds as the retry policy timeout seconds?

Comment: Where can I get the network request timeout amount? If I see from the LogCat, the request lifetime is 3825ms. The retry policy timeout amount is 2500ms (DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS)

Comment: If I look at the source code of `Volley`, I see most Timeouts are set to 5000ms. I guess your post is double because your retry happens before the request timeout has passed, effectively sending it twice.

Comment: Solved in this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936955/i-am-unable-to-make-a-network-call-using-volley-i-have-tried-many-solutions-but/47937201?noredirect=1#comment82844782_47937201

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add the following values to your Request object:

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

**Here:**
request is your object of JsonObjectRequest. Change the value of multiplicator according to the DEFAULT TIMEOUT VALUE in DefaultRetryPolicy class in Volley.

**You can also set the first argument to 0, like below:**

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    0,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: still getting duplicates .. help ??

Comment: You can set your default cache to false

Comment: request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

Make: DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES to 0

Comment: your second answer setting the first value to 0, solved my issue.. thanks mate.

Comment: That surely is not working for my code! Applied that solution for 3 months, but NOPE! doesn't work! I am still facing this issue as of *Today*!

Answer (score 22):

Just setting the Timeout in the RetryPolicy to 0 is too little.
After checking the source, you have to actually set the maximum number of retries < 0, as it is checking current <= max...

I fixed double posting with setting the policy to the following

```
new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. Although you can set the timeout value too

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution for the double post, I just set the timeout to 0.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Setting timeout to 0 should probably lead to more requests firing right?

Comment: Apparently no, it seems 0 means no timeout. As I has discovered, if volley reaches timeout, it will fire another request. So setting timeout to 0 prevent volley from firing another request.

Comment: I'm not too sure on this. I have just increased the timeout to like 30000 ms to just delay things for now.

Comment: It's very bad solution, In my case splash activity send a post request to server and when user doesn't have internet so post request never failed and user is blocked, I think Droid_Mechanic answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

You must set the RetryPolicy to 0 retries and ensure that the timeout is bigger than the server timeout.

```
setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy("bigger than server timeout",
                                      0,
                                      DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for the multi post bug.

Change the RetryPolicy. 
I set the timeout value to 50000ms, worked fine
Like this:

```
  request.setRetryPolicy(
                new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        500000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

I am able to solve this issue by two ways.

First is changed the `RetryPolicy`.
Simply set the timeout value to double of the default timeout. Worked fine. You can also try other values.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Another way is by setting `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);` in `openConnection` method `HurlStack` class.

I am creating my `RequestQueue` like this `requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new HurlStack());`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: How can we set `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);` in `openConnection` method `HurlStack` class? I have tried to extend `HurlStack` but failed. I also tried your first solution but it's failed to.

Comment: In your Volley library project, you can see HurlStack in toolbox package. 
And the first solution should work, try to experiment with different timeout values.

Comment: Yes, i did saw the `HurlStack` class but i can't find any way how to put `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);`. Could you post some demo code? About the first solution, i tried all case, including change time out, change retry to 0 and `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false")` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question here:

[Android Volley makes 2 requests to the server when retry policy is set to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264942/android-volley-makes-2-requests-to-the-server-when-retry-policy-is-set-to-0)

I managed to solve this issue by setting the keep-alive property to false inside Android, e.g.:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false")
```

I added this line of code inside the class where I import requestqueue and make the requests.

Also, check if you server has the keep-alive header.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352424/httpurlconnection-openconnection-fails-second-time) helped get to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

please increase the setRetryPolicy time.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    30000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(equest);
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I got the double requests to stop was to set the retry policy retries to -1

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, 0));
```

I think this is because the DefaultRetryPolicy's logic for attempts remaining returns true if retryCount is 0 and Max retries is also 0 in the hasAttemptRemaining() method:

```
protected boolean hasAttemptRemaining() {
    return this.mCurrentRetryCount <= this.mMaxNumRetries;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
public class MyRetryPolicyWithoutRetry implements RetryPolicy
{
    @override
    public int getCurrentTimeout()
    {
        return CONNECTION_TIME_OUT; /200000/
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError
    {
        throw(error);
    }
}
```

To use:

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new MyRetryPolicyWithoutRetry());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of timeout error
The request is execute twice so you have a double value

Try to increase the timeout error request with this code :

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2,
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by configuring HttpURLConnection like this:

```
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

I started a discussion about this in Volley email list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/volley-users/8PE9dBbD6iA).

Comment: Did you add the line in `HurlStack.java` file?

Comment: Yes, I added it to openConnection() -method where the HttpURLConnection is being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

**Best Solution:**

```
jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 
     DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Volley request policy only one time request to avoid duplicate post

I tried this solution, but does not working

```
//...........solution 01
jsonObjectRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
120000, 
0,
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)


or

//...........solution 02
jsonObjectRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
0, 
-1,
DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)


MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
```

Full Source Code: https://androidkeynotes.blogspot.com/2020/02/volley.html

Answer (score 0):

just `maxNumRetries = 0` no work.
`set TIMEOUT_MS 20000`.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean here?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tried lot of things but in the end nothing helped. Finally, I figured out following combination of changes:

```
sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,-1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

And in your hurl connection in application class, add this:

```
httpsURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

This worked smoothly to stop Volley hitting multiple request at server.

Answer (score 0):

correcting the `android date` fixes my problem unfortunately for testing purpose i have changed my android date and get ssl security error.