# Volley policy send request 2 times

Tags: android-volley, retrypolicy

I am using volley library. I don't want to retry request when user gets time out. I found some answers but they don't fix my problem.

Original library:

```
OwnReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                StaticVariables.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Solution 1: Change `Default_MAX_RETRIES` to 0:

- This is good for HTTP but does not fix HTTPS. If I try to HTTPS domain. Retry 2 times.

Solution 2: Override `RetryPolicy()`:

- Same problem as solution 1. HTPP is ok! but HTPPS try 2 times

This is very important for me and I have no time. Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: you can check this post[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428343/android-volley-double-post-when-have-slow-request

Comment: Thx but this post didn't  help me!