# Android Volley ERROR D/Volley: [486] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests:

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to  get a JSON object using Volley to create a dynamic Auto complete, but on requesting using volley I see this in the log cat:

> D/Volley: [486] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for
>   request=<[ ]
>   https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/suggest-train/train/2/apikey/xnlo6zq3yj/
>   0x2538544 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=5648], [size=363753], [rc=200],
>   [retryCount=0]

My problem was not solved by these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428343/android-volley-double-post-when-have-slow-request).

Here is the Singleton Class which is initializing the Request queue:

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class SingleTon {
    private Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public static SingleTon singleTon;
    public SingleTon(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        requestQueue=getRequestQueue();
    }
    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if(requestQueue==null){
            requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }
    public synchronized static SingleTon getInstance(Context context){
        if(singleTon==null){
            singleTon=new SingleTon(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return singleTon;
    }
    public void addToRequestQueue(Request request){
        requestQueue.add(request).setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy([I have tried all possible combinations here]));
    }
}
```

The method which is making the request:

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter=new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
            if(charSequence!=null){
                String partialName=charSequence.toString();
                String url="https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/suggest-train/train/"+partialName+"/apikey/xnlo6zq3yj/";
                HTTPConnector httpConnector=new HTTPConnector(url,context);
                JSONObject response=httpConnector.getJsonResponse();
                try {
                    JSONArray trains=response.getJSONArray("trains");
                    for(int i=0;i<trains.length();i++){
                        trainName.add(new Train(trains.getJSONObject(i).getString("number")));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                filterResults.values=trainName;
                filterResults.count=trainName.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }
```

Here is the HTTP Connector class:

```
package com.example.mukhe.dynamicautocomplete;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by mukhe on 06-Feb-18.
 */

public class HTTPConnector {
    String url;
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    Context context;
    public HTTPConnector(String url,Context context){
        this.url=url;
        this.context=context;
    }

    public JSONObject getJsonResponse() {
        makeQuery();
        return jsonResponse;
    }
    private void makeQuery(){
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                jsonResponse=response;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("ERROR: ", error.toString());
            }
        });
        SingleTon.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428343/android-volley-double-post-when-have-slow-request

Comment: have u try to hit url in web browser and it takes time how much time to result ?

Comment: I have already mentioned that it didn't help.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/passsy/5947572

Comment: @duggu Yes I have tried. And it didnt take much.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I would have to have the request's response first before caching which I don't.

Comment: I never used Volley to send requests with HTTPConnector Class. I see this class very first time

Comment: And where you are making requests using Volley?

Comment: @ZaidMirza  Yes. The HTTP Connector is a custom made class.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee then you should give us that class code too

Comment: @ZaidMirza I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is weird way you using Volley. Volley is makes Asyncronous HTTP Requests. Your these two lines will not give you results every time

```
 HTTPConnector httpConnector=new HTTPConnector(url,context);
 JSONObject response=httpConnector.getJsonResponse();
```

You are sending async.. request and calling `getJsonResponse` function immediately ? you can't sure about that a response is available when you are calling that function. You should return response when you got response  i.e inside `OnResponse` method of `JsonObjectRequest`

So you should implement communication correctly between `HTTPConnector` Class and Class which contain `getFilter` method.

You can use interface for this. Inside your `HTTPConnector` Class declare interface and implement it on your `Activity`.

```
public class HTTPConnector {
    String url;
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    Context context;
    IMyInterface  mListener;
    public interface IMyInterface
   {
    void sendResponse(JsonObject obj);
   }

    public HTTPConnector(String url,Context context,IMyInterface pListener){
        this.url=url;
        this.context=context;
        mListener=pListener
    }


    public void makeQuery(){
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                jsonResponse=response;
             if(mListener!=null)
           {
            mListener.sendResponse(response);
           }
             }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("ERROR: ", error.toString());
               if(mListener!=null)
                {
                   mListener.sendResponse(null);
                }
            }
        });
        SingleTon.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
}
```

In Your Activity, implement interface and override sendResponse method of interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HTTPConnector.IMyInterface
{
  ...........
  ...........
  // Your other code of activity
  ...........
  ..........

  @Override
  public void sendResponse(JsonObject response)
  {
   try {
       JSONArray trains=response.getJSONArray("trains");
       for(int i=0;i<trains.length();i++){
                    trainName.add(new Train(trains.getJSONObject(i).getString("number")));
                }
               //Now you have response and filled the list, can call getFilter
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

  }

}
```

Somewhere in your activity probably when you have query text for URL. make volley request like below.

```
String url="https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/suggest-train/train/"+partialName+"/apikey/xnlo6zq3yj/";
    HTTPConnector httpConnector=new HTTPConnector(url,context,this); // this will act as your listener
    httpConnector.makeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It helped.

Comment: glad to help you