# Android/Java: How to avoid duplicates in a RequestQueue?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

My app sends data to a server every few minutes. It works fine as long as I'm online. When I'm offline in between, it seems like the `stringRequests` are temporarily stored in the `requestQueue` and fired all together as soon as I establish the internet connection.

To avoid adding duplicates to the `requestQueue`, I'm looking for something like the following pseudo-code:

```
if (!requestQueue.isRequestInQueue(stringRequest)) {
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I'd like to avoid using `requestQueue.cancelAll()`.

Any ideas how to avoid duplicates in a `RequestQueue`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428343/android-volley-double-post-when-have-slow-request

Comment: `setShouldCache - > false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different solutions, I chose `requestQueue.cancelAll()` and it works as expected.

For further information, check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#cancel).