# android volley double request when I use proxy

Tags: android, proxy, android-volley

I have a problem with my code that works very well for me, but when I intercept with a proxy it sends me a double request. I would like to solve that error and only send it once. I was checking the web and I found a similar question but I am new to this language and I don't know how to implement it.

[Android Volley double post when have slow request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428343/android-volley-double-post-when-have-slow-request)

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.pwd);
    final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            final String URL = "https://www.myurl.com/login.php";

            String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
            String pwd = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject r = new JSONObject(response);

                        String status = r.getString("msg");

                        if (status.equals("OK")) {
                            Intent secretIntent = new Intent().setClass(LoginActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(secretIntent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("username", username);
                    params.put("pwd", pwd);
                    return params;
                }

            };
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello I could find the answer, it was actually very simple just add a line to the code

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

here my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.pwd);
    final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            final String URL = "https://www.myurl.com/login.php";

            String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
            String pwd = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject r = new JSONObject(response);

                        String status = r.getString("msg");

                        if (status.equals("OK")) {
                            Intent secretIntent = new Intent().setClass(LoginActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(secretIntent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("username", username);
                    params.put("pwd", pwd);
                    return params;
                }

            };
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
}
```