# Volley - Makes Duplicate POST call at timeout mark

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am having an issue where a duplicate POST request is made when Volley hits its timeout mark.  I am setting the timeout via the DefaultRetryPolicy while also setting the retries to 0. I have tried a few other combinations with no change in behavior.

```
volleyRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(timeout*1000, 0, 1f));
```

I have also tried extending the DefaultRetryPolicy class to be sure the

```
retry(VolleyError error)
```

throws the error without an attempt to retry at any point.

```
class customRetryPolicy extends DefaultRetryPolicy{
    private int mCurrentTimeoutMs;

    /** The current retry count. */
    private int mCurrentRetryCount;

    /** The maximum number of attempts. */
    private final int mMaxNumRetries;

    /** The backoff multiplier for the policy. */
    private final float mBackoffMultiplier;

    /** The default socket timeout in milliseconds */
    public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;

    /** The default number of retries */
    public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 0;

    /** The default backoff multiplier */
    public static final float DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT = 1f;

    /**
     * Constructs a new retry policy using the default timeouts.
     */
    public customRetryPolicy() {
        this(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new retry policy.
     * @param initialTimeoutMs The initial timeout for the policy.
     * @param maxNumRetries The maximum number of retries.
     * @param backoffMultiplier Backoff multiplier for the policy.
     */
    public customRetryPolicy(int initialTimeoutMs, int maxNumRetries, float backoffMultiplier) {
        mCurrentTimeoutMs = initialTimeoutMs;
        mMaxNumRetries = maxNumRetries;
        mBackoffMultiplier = backoffMultiplier;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current timeout.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        return mCurrentTimeoutMs;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current retry count.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
        return mCurrentRetryCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the backoff multiplier for the policy.
     */
    public float getBackoffMultiplier() {
        return mBackoffMultiplier;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares for the next retry by applying a backoff to the timeout.
     * @param error The error code of the last attempt.
     */
    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
        throw error;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this policy has attempts remaining, false otherwise.
     */
    protected boolean hasAttemptRemaining() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, after adding logs I cannot see this method ever being fired when the timeout mark hits.  It does fire for other errors and it is appropriately throwing the error then.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: This is probably because Volley automatically retries if it encounters a network error.

Comment: I do not have a problem with it retrying on other network errors though.  It seems that it only does this when the call is taking an extra long time.

It is also fair to note that if I shorten the timeout to around 5 seconds, I do not have this issue.  Everything gets called as it should. It is when I extend the timeout length that the issue arises.

Comment: It could be a bug. Why not use a timeout of 5 seconds then?

Comment: I, unfortunately, do not get to set the timeout rules.  I am hoping to find a work around solution to this, but so far I have been unable to do so.

Comment: I found a work-around here: [Android Volley makes 2 requests to the server when retry policy is set to 0][1] (see "Edit" paragraph in answer)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26264942/2492742

Comment: Thanks @BaCh, I am including the keep alive header already.  Is that sufficient enough or would setting the system property still be necessary?

Comment: @TDev I don't know, I just set the system property, I didn't try to set keep alive header alone. However, searching for other solution, I found this other useful post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27421424/2492742: overriding createConnection method of HurlStack to set ChunkedStreamingMode to 0 is another way to solve the problem (I tested it successfully)