# PHP if-else bodies both executing

Tags: java, php, android, json, if-statement

I'm a beginner in PHP and i've got this code where both if and else parts are executed in the same "run". I know it's logically impossible but that's what I'm getting.

Here's my PHP Code:

```
<?php

require_once 'create_request_form.php';

$db = new create_request_form();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['rqTitle']) && isset($_POST['rqMname']) && isset($_POST['rqUname']) && isset($_POST['rqBranch']) && isset($_POST['rqText']) && isset($_POST['rqMinPrice']) && isset($_POST['rqMaxPrice']) && isset($_POST['rqImage']) && isset($_POST['rqCategory']) && isset($_POST['rqDateTime'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $rqTitle = $_POST['rqTitle'];
    $rqMname = $_POST['rqMname'];
    $rqUname = $_POST['rqUname'];
    $rqBranch = $_POST['rqBranch'];
    $rqText = $_POST['rqText'];
    $rqMinPrice = $_POST['rqMinPrice'];
    $rqMaxPrice = $_POST['rqMaxPrice'];
    $rqImage = $_POST['rqImage'];
    $rqCategory = $_POST['rqCategory'];
    $rqDateTime = $_POST['rqDateTime'];


    // check if there is a request  with the same title
    if ($db->checkReqTitle($rqTitle)) {
        // Request already exists
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Request already exists with the title: " . $rqTitle;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new request
        $request = $db->StoreReqInfo($rqTitle, $rqMname, $rqUname, $rqBranch, $rqText, $rqMinPrice, $rqMaxPrice, $rqImage, $rqCategory, $rqDateTime);

        if ($request) {
            // request stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["request"]["rqTitle"] = $request["rqTitle"];
            $response["request"]["rqMname"] = $request["rqMname"];
            $response["request"]["rqUname"] = $request["rqUname"];
            $response["request"]["rqBranch"] = $request["rqBranch"];
            $response["request"]["rqText"] = $request["rqText"];
            $response["request"]["rqMinPrice"] = $request["rqMinPrice"];
            $response["request"]["rqMaxPrice"] = $request["rqMaxPrice"];
            $response["request"]["rqImage"] = $request["rqImage"];
            $response["request"]["rqCategory"] = $request["rqCategory"];
            $response["request"]["rqDateTime"] = $request["rqDateTime"];

            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {
            // request failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE; 
            $response["error_msg"] = "An error occurred while creating the request. Please try again.";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
     }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

The required behavior (storing data in the database) is all performed well but the **$response** I'm getting is the error string i've assigned to when a request title already exists instead of the JSON formatted array of the stored request (Both *if* and *else* bodies are executed but i get the result of *if* body as a response).

A screenshot of the $response using Postman to send the request: 
[image]

A screenshot from my Samsung Galaxy Note 3:
[image]

I'm also using Galaxy Note 4 for testing and it just shows me a blank Toast message and doesn't start the intent(doesn't move to home screen).

So far the only possible explanation is that the script is being executed twice, however I can't find anywhere that called it a second time.

This is the java code responsible for sending a request with required paramters to the php script above.

```
 private void storeRequest(final String rTitle, final String rMname, final String rUname,
                          final String rBranch, final String rText,  final String rMinPrice,
                          final String rMaxPrice, final String imagePath, final String rCategory) {

    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "request";

    //A progress dialog message to let the user know they are being registered
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we add your request...");
    showDialog();

    //creating a StringRequest to send the registration info to the script
    // at the server for processing
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_FOR_REQUEST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Request Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try { //json objects must be surrounded by try catch statement
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) { // error is set to false, meaning no error

                    // Launch home activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateRequestActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(CreateRequestActivity.this, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(CreateRequestActivity.this,
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("rqTitle", rTitle);
            params.put("rqText", rText);
            params.put("rqMname", rMname);
            params.put("rqUname", rUname);
            params.put("rqBranch", rBranch);
            params.put("rqMinPrice", rMinPrice);
            params.put("rqMaxPrice", rMaxPrice);
            params.put("rqImage", imagePath);
            params.put("rqCategory", rCategory);
            params.put("rqDateTime", DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check if the java method storeRequest() is called twice?

Comment: it would be great if you also show the output of response variable.

Comment: I've just checked. The java method is only called once.

Comment: I've also updated the post and included screenshots of the responses.

Comment: there is only one response in the postman screenshot, and the response does not contain the "error_msg", is there a second response below that?

Comment: Nope, only the json array. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Thanks @srihs for your comments. Helped me realize the problem came from Java not PHP.

Comment: happy to help! did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the problem stemmed from the Java code and not PHP (poor PHP ;P). More accurately, Volley requests have a problem with request timeouts, especially when sending requests using POST method.

So what worked for me was adding this line right before adding the request to the queue:

```
strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, 0));
```

*Replace *strReq* with your **request** name. Basically what this line does is that it prevents volley from sending a duplicate request when the first request takes too long.

The original & more datailed answer:

> The DefaultRetryPolicy.class's hasAttemptRemaining() class looks like this:
>
> protected boolean hasAttemptRemaining() {
>           return this.mCurrentRetryCount <= this.mMaxNumRetries;
>       }
>       From what I can see, setting the maxNumRetries to 0 will still make that return true if it hasn't done a retry yet.
>
> I fixed it with a
>
> request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, -1, 0);

Source: [Android Volley makes 2 requests to the server when retry policy is set to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264942/android-volley-makes-2-requests-to-the-server-when-retry-policy-is-set-to-0)