# Getting exception "unexpected end of stream" while downloading video in android

Tags: video-streaming, download, android-videoview

I try to download video from server which is big video around 250mb to 300mb in my android application. my code work fine for small video around 30mb to 40mb but I got exception when I download big video. The exception is given bellow:

> 10-28 10:11:57.222: D/Error....(4617): java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
>   10-28 10:11:57.227: W/System.err(4617): java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
>   10-28 10:11:57.232: W/System.err(4617): at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:48)
>   10-28 10:11:57.232: W/System.err(4617):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304)
>   10-28 10:11:57.237: W/System.err(4617):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
>   10-28 10:11:57.237: W/System.err(4617):     at com.photography.khalid.PreviewVideo.DownloadFile(PreviewVideo.java:1079)
>   10-28 10:11:57.237: W/System.err(4617):     at com.photography.khalid.PreviewVideo$DownLoadVideoFile.doInBackground(PreviewVideo.java:1121)
>   10-28 10:11:57.242: W/System.err(4617):     at com.photography.khalid.PreviewVideo$DownLoadVideoFile.doInBackground(PreviewVideo.java:1)
>   10-28 10:11:57.242: W/System.err(4617):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
>   10-28 10:11:57.242: W/System.err(4617):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   10-28 10:11:57.242: W/System.err(4617):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   10-28 10:11:57.247: W/System.err(4617):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
>   10-28 10:11:57.247: W/System.err(4617):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   10-28 10:11:57.252: W/System.err(4617):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   10-28 10:11:57.252: W/System.err(4617):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

I try to find solution on stack over flow using this link
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352424/httpurlconnection-openconnection-fails-second-time/3704083#3704083) but I still get error above on large size video.

my code is given bellow

```
public void DownloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName) {
    try {

        String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Photography";
        /*String RootDir = context.getCacheDir()
                + File.separator + "Photography";*/
        File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
        RootFile.mkdir();
        // File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        //Open a connection to that URL.
        //URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        c.setUseCaches(false); 
        c.setDoInput(true); 

        c.setRequestMethod("POST");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();
        int contentByte=c.getContentLength();
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(RootFile,
                "temp"+fileName));
        //f=openFileOutput("temp"+fileName, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(in, 1024 * 10);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];
        int len1 = 0;

        while ((len1 = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {                          
            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);  
            Log.d("file data", buffer.toString()+",value of progressBarStatus"+progressBarStatus);
            progressBarStatus+=(len1*100.0)/(contentByte)+0.0;
            progressBarHorizontal.setProgress((int)progressBarStatus);
            progressBar2.setProgress((int)progressBarStatus);

            if(isTaskCancelled)
            {
                failToDownload=1;
                break;
            }
        }  
        f.flush();
        f.close();
        inStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error....", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        failToDownload=1;
    }
}
```

If any suggestion then most well come. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that very long video cannot we download using manual code we have to use download manager here I shared link which helpful me to get my task done

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/358107

Comment: give and. related to your que. !

Comment: Due to video size some time server connection we loss because of any reason like low internet and we cannot download it, so we used library to download the video in which they manage all we need and I shared link using I solved my problem.